# Access subform, how to resize columns to best fit?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a subform.  This subform displays the results of a query that is created dynamically (user enters criteria, I build the SQL, then update the querydef and display).  Problem is since the columns are dynamic the width of the columns isn't working out, some are cutting off text.

Is there a way to programmatically loop through the columns (or do the same without loop) and set them all to bestfit width after the query is refreshed?

EDIT:  Here is what my code looks like now:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SearchResults").sql = sql
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh   

Dim qdf1 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fld1 As DAO.Field

Set qdf1 = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SearchResults")

For i = 0 To qdf1.Fields.Count - 1
    Set fld1 = qdf1.Fields(i)
    fld1.CreateProperty "ColumnWidth", dbInteger

    fld1.Properties("ColumnWidth") = -2     'Throws error
    Set fld1 = Nothing
Next i

Me.Child20.SourceObject = "Query.SearchResults"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set column widths like so:

```
Sub SetColumnWidth()
Dim qdf1 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fld1 As DAO.Field

Set qdf1 = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("query3")

For i = 0 To qdf1.Fields.Count - 1
    Set fld1 = qdf1.Fields(i)
    fld1.CreateProperty "ColumnWidth", dbInteger
    'very narrow indeed
    'fld1.Properties("ColumnWidth") = 200
    'Or -2 : Sizes the column to fit the visible text
    'but it is not quite as useful as it would seem
    fld1.Properties("ColumnWidth") = -2
    Set fld1 = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210427

Comment: No, but I only tested with fairly standard queries. The queries were closed when testing.

Comment: What error are you getting? Which version of Access are you using? What is the query type (select, crosstab, etc) ?

Comment: Error says `Run-time error '3270: Property not Found` when trying to set the ColumnWidth.  Using AC2010, the file is an old .mdb.  Query is dynamically built select statement.

Comment: I am running in Access 2010. This line `fld1.CreateProperty "ColumnWidth", dbInteger` creates the property, so it should be found.  When you say dynamically built, is the query saved? Perhaps you could edit your question to shown some code, including how you are using the column width code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I even built a form and ran the code from the live form with the query contained in a subform, and it worked. Have you tried with a blank database, a simple query and a module procedure, just to make sure that it is not related to the database you are working with? Have you compacted and repaired recently? Have you decompiled?

Comment: Compact and repair had no effect.  I'll build a testbed.  But what do you mean by "decompiled"?  I'm familiar with the compile option, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

So I've run into this same problem just now.  I was fortunate enough to have half of my queries work and the other half not.  I've been using this code:

```
Sub QueryData(strSQL As String)
    Dim qryData As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim intcount As Integer

    Set qryData = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DataQuery")
    qryData.SQL = strSQL
    qryData.CreateProperty "ColumnWidth", dbInteger

    qryData.Fields(0).Properties("ColumnWidth") = 5760

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "DataQuery", , acReadOnly
End Sub
```

Which generated the error on half of the queries I tried to run with it.  I traced it back to this odd, but simple truth:  Columns built using an Alias (i.e. all formula columns and expressions) kick out this error.  If the column is just a straight data pull, it works fine.  If the column is, however, a formulated display.... it spits the `no columwidth property` error.

Hopefully this'll help someone out!  I know this questions about a year old, but it was the first result Google found for me on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this grab the open forms and autofit the selected subform within that form. If you have multiple forms/subforms you would just call the function with the new names using the lines of code at the end of the function and pasting them in your program.

```
Public Function AutoSizeSbCtrl(frmNameTar, sbCtrlNameTar)
For Each frm In Forms
    frmName = frm.Name
    If frmName = frmNameTar Then
        For Each frmCtrl In frm.Controls
            frmCtrlName = frmCtrl.Name
            If frmCtrlName = sbCtrlNameTar Then
                For Each sbfrmCtrl In frmCtrl.Controls
                    sbfrmCtrlName = sbfrmCtrl.Name
                    On Error Resume Next
                    sbfrmCtrl.ColumnWidth = -2
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next sbfrmCtrl
            End If
        Next frmCtrl
    End If
Next frm

' paste the lines below in your code where you want it to trigger (i did on an update)
'frmNameTar= "frm12345" ' where frm12345 is the name of the form the subform is in
'sbCtrlNameTar="sbfrm67890" ' where sbfrm67890 is the name of the subform you are trying to autofit
'auSize = AutoSizeSbCtrl(frmNameTar, sbCtrlNameTar)
'end paste
End Function
```